# Remove non-reable characters from BLOB in mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql, aes

I'm using `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` mysql functions on values in the database. However, when I decrypt the values, I get something like this:

`86-0699457����������������������`

And when I do a `var_dump()` of the value, I get just the numbers, but the length of the string is 32, which I'm assuming is because of the question mark characters.

How can I, in either Mysql or PHP, get rid of those unwanted characters?

Comment: What about casting to CHAR(), i.e. `SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(encrypted_text, 'very secret key') AS CHAR(20)) FROM example;`

Comment: @VMai getting the same result from that query..

Answer (score 0):

To make the browser use the correct encoding, add an HTTP header like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

or put the encoding in a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

or Try setting the charset after connecting to your database:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");    
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
```

Comment: Doing all three doesn't solve the problem. I still get those unwanted characters.